# ES6 destructuring not returning correct result

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I an trying to destructure two object with the same property names but only the names of the first set are observed.

```
let a, b,
 ({ a,b } = myObject1);
({ a,b } = myObject2);
```

ie; only the values for myObject1 are in the console.log()

Does anyone know how to destructure properties of the same name from different objects ? I do not want to manually assign each variable.

I had tried

```
let a, b,
     ({ a,b } = myObject1);
    ({ a : test1,b: test2 } = myObject2)
console.log(test1)
```

and

```
  let a, b,
         { a,b } = myObject1;
         { a : test1,b: test2 } = myObject2
    console.log(test1)
```

But test1 is undefined

Comment: That means `myObject2` doesn't have property `a`. As for your original question: How did you expect to have `a` and `b` to have two different values at the same? That's not possible. The last assignment to a variable always wins.

Comment: Undefined likely because you meant to put a comma where that semicolon is.  You could also put `let` before line 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let { a: a1, b: b1 }  = myObject1;
let { a: a2, b: b2 } = myObject2;
```

Will create variables `a1, b1, a2, b2` from your 2 objects.

Comment: a2 is undefined

Comment: if there is no `a` property on `myObject2` then the value of `a2` will be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Assign name to variables.

```
let a, b,
 ({ a,b } = myObject1);
({ a: A,b:B } = myObject2);
```

Comment: A is undefined as mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

If you have more objects with the same structure, you could take a function which returns an array of wanted properties.

```
const getProps = ({ a, b }) => [a, b];

let [a, b] = getProps(myObject1),
    [c, d] = getProps(myObject2);
```